# React Redux -> Why do I get TypeError: state.item is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I am trying to add objects to my redux store but apparently I am doing something wrong. First I define my objects here:

```
 const items=[
    {
        name: 'Blue Dress',
        Price: 540,
    },
    {
        name: 'Red Dress',
        Price: 600,

    }]
```

Then I map them in the return statement:

```
 return(
       <div>
        {items.map(product=>
        <div}>
            <h1>{product.name}</h1>
            <h2>{product.Price}</h2>
            <button onClick={()=>buyProduct(product)}>Buy</button> 

        </div>)}
        
        

       </div>
   )
```

Then after I press the button generated in the return statement I call the following function which is the action trigger:

```
 const buyProduct=(productAdded)=>{

    store.dispatch({type:"buy", payload: productAdded})
  }
```

And then this is my reducer:

```
const reducer=function(state=items, action){
    if(action.type==='buy')
    {
        return {...state, items: [...state.items, action.payload]}
    }
    return state;
```

And those are my store declaration and subsribe:

```
const store = createStore(reducer, 0)
  store.subscribe(()=>{
      console.log('Store is now: ', store.getState())
  })
```

Why do I get the typeError, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but it's confusing to have an array named as a singular.

Comment: You're correct, I totally didn't pay attention!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial) library. Because your React component has no idea the values inside the redux have changed.

Thus, the `items` inside your component is not an array.

Comment: what if I am using it inside a functional component as is the case now?

Comment: Doesn't matter even if it's functional or class components. You could use hooks like `useSelector` and `useDispatch` to hook up your react with redux.

Comment: It might be simpler to use the built-in React hook useReducer which returns both the state and the dispatch: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer